# How to make half-colored text in affinity?

Tags: affinity-designer

I have seen several of this kind of question on this site, but all of them refer to another program, mainly Adobe software. I use Affinity Designer. I want to get a half-colored text like the one in the logo below.

[image]

The "D" in this example is split in half. I would like to do something similar except vertical. If someone could please help me with this that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Just with this black background and white text works also if one simply draws with the pen a yellow shape and gives to it blending mode = multiply. There's already a generally valid answer which doesn't expect white nor black.

Answer (score 2):

the effect you want to achieve is simply done by masking the shape.

Steps:

1/ Convert the text into curves by right clicking on the text element.

[image]

2/ Create a new rectangle element covering the bottom half of the shape representing the letter.

[image]

3/ Move the rectangle in the layer window below the layer with your letter. Not just below linearly but also hierarchically as seen in my screenshot by dragging and dropping it.

[image]

The result looks like this:

[image]

4/ Change the fill of the rectangle

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Affinity Design user, but the same techniques could be used in almost any vector image editing software.

I can think of at least two simple ways it could be achieved. There are probably several more.

1. Using a linear gradient fill on the D with two extra gradient stops in the middle touching each other to form a sharp line between the two
2. Using a rectangle drawn over half of the D, selecting both the D and rectangle, then applying a boolean Divide operation, and filling each piece of the D with a different colour.